# I want my python speech recognition work in between events happening

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping, speech-recognition, pyttsx

Currently I'm working on voice assistant . I have created an event called `get_news()`.

`get_news()` uses web scraping to get news from a website .
I have used Python *speech recognition* module To recognize my voice and 
`Pyttsx3` module to read the news that **get_news()** saves in a **.txt** file

But I have to wait till the whole news is read by my voice assistant .
I want speech recognition to keep listening even when the news is read and should stop reading when I say stop .

Is there any way to accomplish this task
please help me out .

I thought of using threads but I dont know if it works